# adt: logcat not filtering

Tags: android, adt, logcat, android-logcat

I want to filter message from my app (com.android.perl) so I launch:

```
logcat com.android.perl:V
```

however, this command displays all system log!

When I try to create a filter in eclipse with same argument, it works! What is the problem with my command?

Edit1: It's on a real device

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try :
`adb -d logcat <your package name>:<log level> *:S`

Comment: It is on a real device or on the emulator ?

Comment: Strange ... rooted device ? which brand ?

Comment: Well. If you use Linux, you can find a solution using `adb`, `grep` & `tail`... But I dont know why you can't filter :/

Comment: I'm actually under linux and I use grep, but, for some other reason, some logs appear in eclipse but not in cmd.